# chrome extension tabAction without background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to have pageAction defined for one website? I saw  the samples and both of them use `background.js` to show `chrome.pageAction.show(tabId)` in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a pageAction for a specific website, two methods exist.

### Using a content script

Run the content script at the specific website, and pass a message to the background requesting the page action:

```
// contentscript.js
chrome.extension.sendMessage('showPageAction');
// background.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    if (message == 'showPageAction') {
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
});
```

Part of `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": ["http://example.com/"]
}]
```

Valid values for `matches` are exactly defined in the documentation, [match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).
<sup>Note that the match pattern in this example matches `http://example.com/` and not `http://example.com/index.html`. If you want to match anything on the website, use `http://example.com/*` (appended a asterisk).</sup>

### Using the `chrome.tabs` API

If you don't want to use content scripts, you can use `chrome.tabs` events to show the page action:

```
// background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.url == 'http://example.com/') {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
});
```

I recommend the content script method, unless you're already using the [`chrome.tabs`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) API. Why? If you request the `"tabs"` permission in the manifest file, your users will see the following warning on installation:

> Install `<name of your extension>`?
>     It can access:
>     **Access your tabs and browsing activity**

Comment: So the answer is, No ;)  Always wondered why page actions couldnt have a matches key like content scripts.  Also if all your background page is going to do is this, then look at Event Pages so it doesnt hang around when its not needed.